# "Expression.Error: A cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation"

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Got this error after I have written a m code in power bi i.e 'Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Month Name", "Custom", each if [Fiscal Year]= List.Max(#"dim_date"[Fiscal Year]) then "Y" else "N")'. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Post entire M code

Comment: Is #"dim_date" a later function than your Add Column step?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.